# Using Volley For Spoonacular Api

Tags: api, android-studio, android-volley

How to use Volley to fetch recipes from spoonacular API for an android application. I am new to APIs and would like some help in fetching recipes from the spoonacular api for a list of ingredients specified in an android app.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1

> 

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

Step 2
In AndroidManifest file add permission

> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
>   Step 3 Add following in MyApplication class

```
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (requestQueue == null)
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    return requestQueue;
}


public void addToRequestQueue(Request request, String tag) {
        request.setTag(tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(request);
    }
public void cancelAllRequests(String tag) {
        getRequestQueue().cancelAll(tag);
    }
```

> Step 4 Final Step

```
//URL of the request we are sending
String url = "https://api.spoonacular.com/food/products/22347";
/*
JsonObjectRequest takes in five paramaters
Request Type - This specifies the type of the request eg: GET,
URL - This String param specifies the Request URL
JSONObject - This parameter takes in the POST parameters.null in case of
GET request
Listener -This parameter takes in a implementation of Response.Listener()
interface which is invoked if the request is successful
Listener -This parameter takes in a implemention of Error.Listener()
interface which is invoked if any error is encountered while processing
the request
*/
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
    url, null,
    new Response.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //Success Callback
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //Failure Callback
        }
    });
// Adding the request to the queue along with a unique string tag
MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectReq, "getRequest");
```

> Something like that. Let's try. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much Haseeb. I will surely try it out.

Comment: I am getting an error at   requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()); and how do you pass queries so that the user is provided with a recipe of ingredients he has provided? Thank you for your time.

Comment: did you add MyApplication Class in Android Manifest   <application
android:name=".MyApplication"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

Comment: Let fix Volley.newRequestQueue Error first. Then move forward to recipe ingredients query.

Comment: Yeah, I just added it in Android Manifest -

<application
        android:name="MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


But I still have the error...